# Asp.Net Core Routing to an area controller with Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I have my routing setup in Startup.cs like this

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

          routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

and a controller configured like this:

```
[Area("Pad")]
public class RequestsController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
   ....
     }
}
```

on my home page I have a link setup to go to this controller:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("PAD","Index","Requests",new{area="Pad"},null)
```

only this renders the link as

```
<a href="/Pad/Requests">PAD</a>
```

when the actual url for the controller seems to be

```
https://localhost:44358/Pad/Pad/Requests
```

I don't understand how this is worked out and where the extra "Pad" in the url is coming from.  Can anyone enlighten me.

Comment: Where do you get this link `/Pad/Pad/Requests` from? The one rendered by `ActionLink` is right

Comment: What do you mean by `when the actual url for the controller seems to be`? Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Alexander  - I believe the one rendered by the action link is correct also..but it gives a 404 error, the /Pad/Pad/Requests is the one that actually works

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else comes across this weirdness,  I managed to solve this by creating a new project and adding all the code into it bit by it.  I thought this would help me identify the problem, instead it just went away!